# How can I convert a byte array to hexadecimal in Java?

Tags: java

I have an array of bytes. I want each byte String of that array to be converted to its corresponding hexadecimal value.

Is there any function in Java to convert a byte array to Hexadecimal?

Comment: What you call byte-array in Java is called byte string in other languages (e.g. https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/bytestrings.html)

Answer (score 354):

```java
byte[] bytes = {-1, 0, 1, 2, 3 };
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (byte b : bytes) {
    sb.append(String.format("%02X ", b));
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
// prints "FF 00 01 02 03 "
```

#### See also

- [`java.util.Formatter` syntax](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

  - `%[flags][width]conversion`

    - Flag `'0'` - The result will be zero-padded
    - Width `2`
    - Conversion `'X'` - The result is formatted as a hexadecimal integer, uppercase

---

Looking at the text of the question, it's also possible that this is what is requested:

```java
String[] arr = {"-1", "0", "10", "20" };
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = String.format("%02x", Byte.parseByte(arr[i]));
}
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(arr));
// prints "[ff, 00, 0a, 14]"
```

---

Several answers here uses [`Integer.toHexString(int)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString%28int%29); this is doable, but with some caveats. Since the parameter is an `int`, a widening primitive conversion is performed to the `byte` argument, which involves sign extension.

```java
byte b = -1;
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(b));
// prints "ffffffff"
```

The 8-bit `byte`, which is signed in Java, is sign-extended to a 32-bit `int`. To effectively undo this sign extension, one can mask the `byte` with `0xFF`.

```java
byte b = -1;
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xFF));
// prints "ff"
```

Another issue with using `toHexString` is that it doesn't pad with zeroes:

```java
byte b = 10;
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xFF));
// prints "a"
```

Both factors combined should make the `String.format` solution more preferable.

#### References

- [JLS 4.2.1 Integral Types and Values](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.2.1)

  - For `byte`, from `-128` to `127`, inclusive
- [JLS 5.1.2 Widening Primitive Conversion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.2)

Comment: @Vivek: what is "an enormously large value"? What's the input and what's the output?

Comment: Let me explain again.. I have a collection of byte strings in an array. But what i have to do is analyse each byte seperately.. So, I dont want to work on the whole array, but individual byte string at a time, that is one component of that array.. The confusion arised because of the word "array". Now in the below code " byte bv = 10; String hexString = Integer.toHexString(bv); "               CAse 1 (Byte Recieved : 68 Hex Output : : 44)  
              Case : 2 (Byte Recieved : -46 Hex Output : : ffffffd2).........              
 Why am I getting such an unexpected result for some values ?

Comment: @Vivek: read my answer about using `toHexString`. You have to mask it with `& 0xFF`, i.e. `Integer.toHexString(-46 & 0xFF)` is `"d2"`.

Comment: @polygenelubricants : Thanx a lot.. It seems, finally the code is working fine..  Is it safe to usen toHexString function now ? Or, there might be some loopholes with the approach ?

Comment: @Vivek: it's "safe", you just have to be careful and make sure you mask the `byte` value with `& 0xFF` every time. the `format` solution above may also require masking depending on what you're actually using as argument.

Comment: @polygenelubricants I have same problem, and tried String.format("%02x", intValue), however when intValue = -1, the result I got is ffffffff instead of ff, can you help tell why?

Comment: What does it mean: The result will be zero-padded ?
What's that for?

Answer (score 80):

I am posting because none of the existing answers explain why their approaches work, which I think is really important for this problem. In some cases, this causes the proposed solution to appear unnecessarily complicated and subtle.  To illustrate I will provide a fairly straightforward approach, but I'll provide a bit more detail to help illustrate **why** it works.

First off, what are we trying to do? We want to convert a byte value (or an array of bytes) to a string which represents a hexadecimal value in ASCII. So step one is to find out exactly what a byte in Java is:

> The byte data type is an **8-bit signed two's complement integer**. It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive). The byte data type can be useful for saving memory in large arrays, where the memory savings actually matters. They can also be used in place of int where their limits help to clarify your code; the fact that a variable's range is limited can serve as a form of documentation.

What does this mean? A few things: First and most importantly, it means we are working with **8-bits**. So for example we can write the number 2 as 0000 0010. However, since it is two's complement, we write a negative 2 like this: 1111 1110. What is also means is that converting to hex is very straightforward. That is, you simply convert each 4 bit segment directly to hex. Note that to make sense of negative numbers in this scheme you will first need to understand two's complement. If you don't already understand two's complement, you can read an excellent explanation, here: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~tomf/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html

---

## Converting Two's Complement to Hex In General

Once a number is in two's complement it is dead simple to convert it to hex. In general, converting from binary to hex is very straightforward, and as you will see in the next two examples, you can go directly from two's complement to hex.

### Examples

**Example 1:** Convert 2 to Hex.

1) First convert 2 to binary in two's complement:

```
2 (base 10) = 0000 0010 (base 2)
```

2) Now convert binary to hex:

```
0000 = 0x0 in hex
0010 = 0x2 in hex

therefore 2 = 0000 0010 = 0x02.
```

**Example 2:** Convert -2 (in two's complement) to Hex.

1) First convert -2 to binary in two's complement:

```
-2 (base 10) = 0000 0010 (direct conversion to binary) 
               1111 1101 (invert bits)
               1111 1110 (add 1)
therefore: -2 = 1111 1110 (in two's complement)
```

2) Now Convert to Hex:

```
1111 = 0xF in hex
1110 = 0xE in hex

therefore: -2 = 1111 1110 = 0xFE.
```

---

## Doing this In Java

Now that we've covered the concept, you'll find we can achieve what we want with some simple masking and shifting. The key thing to understand is that **the byte you are trying to convert is already in two's complement.** You don't do this conversion yourself. I think this is a major point of confusion on this issue. Take for example the follow byte array:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[]{-2,2};
```

We just manually converted them to hex, above, but how can we do it in Java? Here's how:

**Step 1:** Create a StringBuffer to hold our computation.

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
```

**Step 2:** Isolate the higher order bits, convert them to hex, and append them to the buffer

Given the binary number 1111 1110, we can isolate the higher order bits by first shifting them over by 4, and then zeroing out the rest of the number. Logically this is simple, however, the implementation details in Java (and many languages) introduce a wrinkle because of sign extension. Essentially, when you shift a byte value, Java first converts your value to an integer, and then performs sign extension. So while you would expect 1111 1110 >> 4 to be 0000 1111, in reality, in Java it is represented as the two's complement 0xFFFFFFFF!

So returning to our example:

```
1111 1110 >> 4 (shift right 4) = 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 (32 bit sign-extended number in two's complement)
```

We can then isolate the bits with a mask:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 & 0xF = 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111
therefore: 1111 = 0xF in hex.
```

In Java we can do this all in one shot:

```
Character.forDigit((bytes[0] >> 4) & 0xF, 16);
```

The forDigit function just maps the number you pass it onto the set of hexadecimal numbers 0-F.

**Step 3:** Next we need to isolate the lower order bits. Since the bits we want are already in the correct position, we can just mask them out:

```
1111 1110 & 0xF = 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1110 (recall sign extension from before)
therefore: 1110 = 0xE in hex.
```

Like before, in Java we can do this all in one shot:

```
Character.forDigit((bytes[0] & 0xF), 16);
```

Putting this all together we can do it as a for loop and convert the entire array:

```
for(int i=0; i < bytes.length; i++){
    buffer.append(Character.forDigit((bytes[i] >> 4) & 0xF, 16));
    buffer.append(Character.forDigit((bytes[i] & 0xF), 16));
}
```

Hopefully this explanation makes things clearer for those of you wondering exactly what is going on in the many examples you will find on the internet. Hopefully I didn't make any egregious errors, but suggestions and corrections are highly welcome!

Comment: best answer! The symetric implementation of a hex String to byte would convertion then use `Character.digit()`, like `(byte) ((Character.digit(str.charAt(0), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(str.charAt(1), 16))`

Answer (score 25):

The **fastest** way i've yet found to do this is the following:

```java
private static final String    HEXES    = "0123456789ABCDEF";

static String getHex(byte[] raw) {
    final StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(2 * raw.length);
    for (final byte b : raw) {
        hex.append(HEXES.charAt((b & 0xF0) >> 4)).append(HEXES.charAt((b & 0x0F)));
    }
    return hex.toString();
}
```

It's ~ 50x faster than `String.format`. if you want to test it:

```
public class MyTest{
    private static final String    HEXES        = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    @Test
    public void test_get_hex() {
        byte[] raw = {
            (byte) 0xd0, (byte) 0x0b, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x2a, (byte) 0x63,
            (byte) 0x78, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x2e, (byte) 0xe3, (byte) 0x6c,
            (byte) 0xd2, (byte) 0xb0, (byte) 0x78, (byte) 0x51, (byte) 0x73,
            (byte) 0x34, (byte) 0xaf, (byte) 0xbb, (byte) 0xa0, (byte) 0x9f,
            (byte) 0xc3, (byte) 0xa9, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x1e, (byte) 0xd5,
            (byte) 0x4b, (byte) 0x89, (byte) 0xa3, (byte) 0x45, (byte) 0x35,
            (byte) 0xd6, (byte) 0x10,
        };

        int N = 77777;
        long t;

        {
            t = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                final StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(2 * raw.length);
                for (final byte b : raw) {
                    hex.append(HEXES.charAt((b & 0xF0) >> 4)).append(HEXES.charAt((b & 0x0F)));
                }
                hex.toString();
            }
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - t); // 50
        }

        {
            t = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(2 * raw.length);
                for (byte b : raw) {
                    hex.append(String.format("%02X", b));
                }
                hex.toString();
            }
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - t); // 2535
        }

    }
}
```

**Edit**: Just found something just a lil faster and that holds on one line but is **not compatible** with JRE 9. **Use at your own risks**

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(raw);
```

Comment: DatatypeConverter is no longer available in Java 9.  The dangerous thing is code using it will compile under Java 1.8 or earlier (Java 9 with source settings to earlier), but get a runtime exception under Java 9.

Comment: I second @StephenMs point: using this with jre9 will crash with ClassNotFound Exception

Comment: Actually can simply extract the source code method  `printHexBinary`  from src.zip of jdk, which seems 1 time  faster than 1st method.

Comment: If you work with char array for HEXES constant, instead String and charAt(), you gain ~20% more speed.

Answer (score 17):

Try this way:

```
byte bv = 10;
String hexString = Integer.toHexString(bv);
```

Dealing with array (if I understood you correctly):

```
byte[] bytes = {9, 10, 11, 15, 16};
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
for (byte b : bytes) {
    result.append(String.format("%02X ", b));
    result.append(" "); // delimiter
}
return result.toString();
```

As polygenelubricants mentioned, `String.format()` is the right answer compare to `Integer.toHexString()` (since it deals with negative numbers in a right way).

Comment: This will sign extend, e.g. try `-1`.

Comment: byte bv = 10; 
String hexString = Integer.toHexString(bv); 

This seems to work firne.. I can apply it individually on every element of the array.. 
The other code (Dealing with array ) gives back too large a value. What could bw the reaason for that ?

Comment: @Vivek, that's because in case of `bv` it returns a **single hexadecimal character**. Whereas the rest of code returns a **string of hexadecimal characters**. I've changed the code with the delimeter so you can understand it now.

Comment: @Bar: you can still use `Integer.toHexString` if you mask the `byte` with `0xFF` to undo sign extension.

Comment: CAse 1 (Byte Recieved : 68 Hex Output : : 44) 
Case : 2 (Byte Recieved : -46 Hex Output : : ffffffd2)

I am getting unexpected output values in case of negative byte arrays ... How to handle this ?

Answer (score 17):

A short and simple way to convert `byte[]` to hex string by using `BigInteger`:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

byte[] bytes = new byte[] {(byte)255, 10, 20, 30};
String hex = new BigInteger(1, bytes).toString(16);
System.out.println(hex); // ff0a141e
```

### How It Works?

The built-in system class `java.math.BigInteger` class ([java.math.BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html)) is compatible with binary and hex data:

- Its has a constructor `BigInteger(signum=1, byte[])` to create a big integer by `byte[]` (set its first parameter `signum` = `1` to handle correctly the negative bytes)
- Use `BigInteger.toString(16)` to convert the big integer to **hex** string
- To parse a hex number use `new BigInteger("ffa74b", 16)` - does not handle correctly the leading zero

If you may want to have the **leading zero** in the hex result, check its size and add the missing zero if necessary:

```
if (hex.length() % 2 == 1)
    hex = "0" + hex;
```

### Notes

Use `new BigInteger(1, bytes)`, instead of `new BigInteger(bytes)`, because Java is "**broken by design**" and the `byte` data type does not hold bytes but signed tiny integers [-128...127]. If the first byte is negative, the `BigInteger` assumes you pass a negative big integer. Just pass `1` as first parameter (`signum=1`).

The conversion back **from hex to `byte[]`** is tricky: sometimes a leading zero enters in the produced output and it should be cleaned like this:

```
byte[] bytes = new BigInteger("ffa74b", 16).toByteArray();
if (bytes[0] == 0) {
    byte[] newBytes = new byte[bytes.length - 1];
    System.arraycopy(bytes, 1, newBytes, 0, newBytes.length);
    bytes = newBytes;
}
```

The last note is the if the `byte[]` has several leading zeroes, they will be lost.

Comment: If the leading byte has a decimal value of less than 16 you will also get a string with an odd number of hex characters.

Answer (score 12):

The Best solution is this badass one-liner:

```
String hex=DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(byte[] b);
```

as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5942951/6263968)

Comment: DatatypeConverter is no longer available in Java 9. The dangerous thing is code using it will compile under Java 1.8 or earlier (Java 9 with source settings to earlier), but get a runtime exception under Java 9.

Comment: Sad when you say its not in jdk9. `new BigInteger(byteArray).toString(16)` is the way to go then. Are are perf issues with that??

Comment: Maybe not perf issues, but it will miss leading zeros (as they are meaningless to a number like BigInteger is)

Comment: Looks like it's still [in the java 9 docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#printHexBinary-byte:A-), so seems like it's ok to use it still from what I can tell

Comment: i think as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46852065/java-9-module-java-xml-bind-is-not-accessible-in-eclipse) it is still ok to use for java9, but will be [removed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java.xml.bind-summary.html) in future java releases. you will also still be able to use it with the 'new' standalone jaxb module as of [version 2.3.0](https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/doc/user-guide/ch02.html#a-2-3-0).

Answer (score 11):

If you want a constant-width hex representation, i.e. `0A` instead of `A`, so that you can recover the bytes unambiguously, try `format()`:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for (byte bb : byteArray) {
    result.append(String.format("%02X", bb));
}
return result.toString();
```

Answer (score 9):

## Java 17: Introducing *java.util.HexFormat*

Java 17 comes with a utility to convert byte arrays and numbers to their hexadecimal counterparts. Let's say we have an MD5 digest of "Hello World" as a byte-array:

```java
var md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
md5.update("Hello world".getBytes(UTF_8));

var digest = md5.digest();
```

Now we can use the **`HexFormat.of().formatHex(byte[])`** method to convert the given `byte[]` to its hexadecimal form:

```java
jshell> HexFormat.of().formatHex(digest)
$7 ==> "3e25960a79dbc69b674cd4ec67a72c62"
```

The `withUpperCase()` method returns the uppercase version of the previous output:

```java
jshell> HexFormat.of().withUpperCase().formatHex(digest)
$8 ==> "3E25960A79DBC69B674CD4EC67A72C62"
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are happy to use an external library, the `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex` class has an `encodeHex` method which takes a `byte[]` and returns a `char[]`. This methods is MUCH faster than the format option, and encapsulates the details of the conversion. Also comes with a `decodeHex` method for the opposite conversion.

Comment: An even easier way is to use the built-in functions javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter/parseHexBinary and printHexBinary.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/convert-from-byte-array-to-hex-string-in-java

Comment: +1 to this option. The Hex also has a method encodeHexString, which takes a byte[] and returns a String.

Comment: don't forget that the `javax` namespace isn't always available.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the method from [Bouncy Castle Provider](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.60) library:

```
org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex.toHexString(byteArray);
```

> The Bouncy Castle Crypto package is a Java implementation of
>   cryptographic algorithms. This jar contains JCE provider and
>   lightweight API for the Bouncy Castle Cryptography APIs for JDK 1.5 to
>   JDK 1.8.

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.60</version>
</dependency>
```

or from [Apache Commons Codec](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.11):

```
org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.encodeHexString(byteArray);
```

> The Apache Commons Codec package contains simple encoder and decoders
>   for various formats such as Base64 and Hexadecimal. In addition to
>   these widely used encoders and decoders, the codec package also
>   maintains a collection of phonetic encoding utilities.

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yes, this is **the best solution**, but requires an external library: **Apache Commons Codec** (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.11) or **BouncyCastle Provider** (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.60)

Answer (score 6):

This is the code that I've found to run the fastest so far. I ran it on 109015 byte arrays of length 32, in 23ms. I was running it on a VM so it'll probably run faster on bare metal.

```
public static final char[] HEX_DIGITS =         {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};

public static char[] encodeHex( final byte[] data ){
    final int l = data.length;
    final char[] out = new char[l<<1];
    for( int i=0,j=0; i<l; i++ ){
        out[j++] = HEX_DIGITS[(0xF0 & data[i]) >>> 4];
        out[j++] = HEX_DIGITS[0x0F & data[i]];
    }
    return out;
}
```

Then you can just do

```
String s = new String( encodeHex(myByteArray) );
```

Comment: Nice to skip StringBuilder... Does your benchmark include the `String` creation time?

Answer (score 5):

```
BigInteger n = new BigInteger(byteArray);
String hexa = n.toString(16);
```

Comment: Doesn't work: `BigInteger(byteArrayOf(-1, 2, 3, 4, 5)).toString(16)` returns `"-fdfcfbfb"`

Comment: It's a right result. You working with bytes '-1', '2' ... '5'. Thats bytes no have visualiztion (http://www.unicode.org) if you intention is work with the literal '-1', '2' ... '5' you should work with the string values.

Comment: It is wrong result. Java byte value of -1 is in fact 0xFF (it's the same as `(int) 255`) since Java bytes are signed, so the result should be `FF02030405`. If you try out @Jerinaw solution above you'll see it will print the correct output. Also see Svetlin Nakov's solution below.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple function to convert byte to Hexadecimal

```
   private static String convertToHex(byte[] data) {
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        int halfbyte = (data[i] >>> 4) & 0x0F;
        int two_halfs = 0;
        do {
            if ((0 <= halfbyte) && (halfbyte <= 9))
                buf.append((char) ('0' + halfbyte));
            else
                buf.append((char) ('a' + (halfbyte - 10)));
            halfbyte = data[i] & 0x0F;
        } while(two_halfs++ < 1);
    }
    return buf.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Others have covered the general case. But if you have a byte array of a known form, for example a MAC address, then you can:

```
byte[] mac = { (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00 };

String str = String.format("%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X",
                           mac[0], mac[1], mac[2], mac[3], mac[4], mac[5]);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a very fast way. No external libaries needed.

```
final protected static char[] HEXARRAY = "0123456789abcdef".toCharArray();

    public static String encodeHexString( byte[] bytes ) {

        char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
        for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
            int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = HEXARRAY[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = HEXARRAY[v & 0x0F];
        }
        return new String(hexChars);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There's your fast method:

```
    private static final String[] hexes = new String[]{
        "00","01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","0A","0B","0C","0D","0E","0F",
        "10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","1A","1B","1C","1D","1E","1F",
        "20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","2A","2B","2C","2D","2E","2F",
        "30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","3A","3B","3C","3D","3E","3F",
        "40","41","42","43","44","45","46","47","48","49","4A","4B","4C","4D","4E","4F",
        "50","51","52","53","54","55","56","57","58","59","5A","5B","5C","5D","5E","5F",
        "60","61","62","63","64","65","66","67","68","69","6A","6B","6C","6D","6E","6F",
        "70","71","72","73","74","75","76","77","78","79","7A","7B","7C","7D","7E","7F",
        "80","81","82","83","84","85","86","87","88","89","8A","8B","8C","8D","8E","8F",
        "90","91","92","93","94","95","96","97","98","99","9A","9B","9C","9D","9E","9F",
        "A0","A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6","A7","A8","A9","AA","AB","AC","AD","AE","AF",
        "B0","B1","B2","B3","B4","B5","B6","B7","B8","B9","BA","BB","BC","BD","BE","BF",
        "C0","C1","C2","C3","C4","C5","C6","C7","C8","C9","CA","CB","CC","CD","CE","CF",
        "D0","D1","D2","D3","D4","D5","D6","D7","D8","D9","DA","DB","DC","DD","DE","DF",
        "E0","E1","E2","E3","E4","E5","E6","E7","E8","E9","EA","EB","EC","ED","EE","EF",
        "F0","F1","F2","F3","F4","F5","F6","F7","F8","F9","FA","FB","FC","FD","FE","FF"
    };

    public static String byteToHex(byte b) {
        return hexes[b&0xFF];
    }
```

Comment: ugly, but probably very efficient. :-)

Comment: Come on. You can do better than this :-) (Hint: Two nested for-loops and constructed as a static variable so executed only once during class loading (cinit) time)

Answer (score 2):

Just like some other answers, I recommend to use `String.format()` and `BigInteger`. But to interpret the byte array as [big-endian binary representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) instead of [two's-complement binary representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) (with signum and incomplete use of possible hex values range) use [BigInteger(int signum, byte[] magnitude)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-int-byte:A-), not [BigInteger(byte[] val)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-byte:A-).

For example, for a byte array of length 8 use:

```
String.format("%016X", new BigInteger(1,bytes))
```

Advantages:

- leading zeros
- no signum
- only built-in functions
- only one line of code

Disadvantage:

- there might be more efficient ways to do that

Example:

```java
byte[] bytes = new byte[8];
Random r = new Random();
System.out.println("big-endian       | two's-complement");
System.out.println("-----------------|-----------------");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    r.nextBytes(bytes);
    System.out.print(String.format("%016X", new BigInteger(1,bytes)));
    System.out.print(" | ");
    System.out.print(String.format("%016X", new BigInteger(bytes)));
    System.out.println();
}
```

Example output:

```
big-endian       | two's-complement
-----------------|-----------------
3971B56BC7C80590 | 3971B56BC7C80590
64D3C133C86CCBDC | 64D3C133C86CCBDC
B232EFD5BC40FA61 | -4DCD102A43BF059F
CD350CC7DF7C9731 | -32CAF338208368CF
82CDC9ECC1BC8EED | -7D3236133E437113
F438C8C34911A7F5 | -BC7373CB6EE580B
5E99738BE6ACE798 | 5E99738BE6ACE798
A565FE5CE43AA8DD | -5A9A01A31BC55723
032EBA783D2E9A9F | 032EBA783D2E9A9F
8FDAA07263217ABA | -70255F8D9CDE8546
```

Comment: Another disadvantage is that you have to know the length of the byte array upfront. But `String.format("%0" + (bytes.length * 2) + "x", new BigInteger(1, bytes))` is easy enough, if a little ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Creating (and destroying) a bunch of `String` instances is not a good way if performance is an issue.

Please ignore those verbose (duplicate) arguments checking statements (`if`s). That's for (another) educational purposes.

Full maven project: http://jinahya.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/com.googlecode.jinahya/hex-codec/

Encoding...

```
/**
 * Encodes a single nibble.
 *
 * @param decoded the nibble to encode.
 *
 * @return the encoded half octet.
 */
protected static int encodeHalf(final int decoded) {

    switch (decoded) {
        case 0x00:
        case 0x01:
        case 0x02:
        case 0x03:
        case 0x04:
        case 0x05:
        case 0x06:
        case 0x07:
        case 0x08:
        case 0x09:
            return decoded + 0x30; // 0x30('0') - 0x39('9')
        case 0x0A:
        case 0x0B:
        case 0x0C:
        case 0x0D:
        case 0x0E:
        case 0x0F:
            return decoded + 0x57; // 0x41('a') - 0x46('f')
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("illegal half: " + decoded);
    }
}


/**
 * Encodes a single octet into two nibbles.
 *
 * @param decoded the octet to encode.
 * @param encoded the array to which each encoded nibbles are written.
 * @param offset the offset in the array.
 */
protected static void encodeSingle(final int decoded, final byte[] encoded,
                                   final int offset) {

    if (encoded == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("null encoded");
    }

    if (encoded.length < 2) {
        // not required
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "encoded.length(" + encoded.length + ") < 2");
    }

    if (offset < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("offset(" + offset + ") < 0");
    }

    if (offset >= encoded.length - 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "offset(" + offset + ") >= encoded.length(" + encoded.length
            + ") - 1");
    }

    encoded[offset] = (byte) encodeHalf((decoded >> 4) & 0x0F);
    encoded[offset + 1] = (byte) encodeHalf(decoded & 0x0F);
}


/**
 * Decodes given sequence of octets into a sequence of nibbles.
 *
 * @param decoded the octets to encode
 *
 * @return the encoded nibbles.
 */
protected static byte[] encodeMultiple(final byte[] decoded) {

    if (decoded == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("null decoded");
    }

    final byte[] encoded = new byte[decoded.length << 1];

    int offset = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < decoded.length; i++) {
        encodeSingle(decoded[i], encoded, offset);
        offset += 2;
    }

    return encoded;
}


/**
 * Encodes given sequence of octets into a sequence of nibbles.
 *
 * @param decoded the octets to encode.
 *
 * @return the encoded nibbles.
 */
public byte[] encode(final byte[] decoded) {

    return encodeMultiple(decoded);
}
```

Decoding...

```
/**
 * Decodes a single nibble.
 *
 * @param encoded the nibble to decode.
 *
 * @return the decoded half octet.
 */
protected static int decodeHalf(final int encoded) {

    switch (encoded) {
        case 0x30: // '0'
        case 0x31: // '1'
        case 0x32: // '2'
        case 0x33: // '3'
        case 0x34: // '4'
        case 0x35: // '5'
        case 0x36: // '6'
        case 0x37: // '7'
        case 0x38: // '8'
        case 0x39: // '9'
            return encoded - 0x30;
        case 0x41: // 'A'
        case 0x42: // 'B'
        case 0x43: // 'C'
        case 0x44: // 'D'
        case 0x45: // 'E'
        case 0x46: // 'F'
            return encoded - 0x37;
        case 0x61: // 'a'
        case 0x62: // 'b'
        case 0x63: // 'c'
        case 0x64: // 'd'
        case 0x65: // 'e'
        case 0x66: // 'f'
            return encoded - 0x57;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("illegal half: " + encoded);
    }
}


/**
 * Decodes two nibbles into a single octet.
 *
 * @param encoded the nibble array.
 * @param offset the offset in the array.
 *
 * @return decoded octet.
 */
protected static int decodeSingle(final byte[] encoded, final int offset) {

    if (encoded == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("null encoded");
    }

    if (encoded.length < 2) {
        // not required
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "encoded.length(" + encoded.length + ") < 2");
    }

    if (offset < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("offset(" + offset + ") < 0");
    }

    if (offset >= encoded.length - 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "offset(" + offset + ") >= encoded.length(" + encoded.length
            + ") - 1");
    }

    return (decodeHalf(encoded[offset]) << 4)
           | decodeHalf(encoded[offset + 1]);
}


/**
 * Encodes given sequence of nibbles into a sequence of octets.
 *
 * @param encoded the nibbles to decode.
 *
 * @return the encoded octets.
 */
protected static byte[] decodeMultiple(final byte[] encoded) {

    if (encoded == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("null encoded");
    }

    if ((encoded.length & 0x01) == 0x01) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "encoded.length(" + encoded.length + ") is not even");
    }

    final byte[] decoded = new byte[encoded.length >> 1];

    int offset = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < decoded.length; i++) {
        decoded[i] = (byte) decodeSingle(encoded, offset);
        offset += 2;
    }

    return decoded;
}


/**
 * Decodes given sequence of nibbles into a sequence of octets.
 *
 * @param encoded the nibbles to decode.
 *
 * @return the decoded octets.
 */
public byte[] decode(final byte[] encoded) {

    return decodeMultiple(encoded);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out what exactly you meant by byte String, but here are some conversions from byte to String and vice versa, of course there is a lot more on the official documentations

```
Integer intValue = 149;
```

The corresponding byte value is:

```
Byte byteValue = intValue.byteValue(); // this will convert the rightmost byte of the intValue to byte, because Byte is an 8 bit object and Integer is at least 16 bit, and it will give you a signed number in this case -107
```

get the integer value back from a Byte variable:

```
Integer anInt = byteValue.intValue(); // This will convert the byteValue variable to a signed Integer
```

**From Byte and Integer to hex String:**
This is the way I do it:

```
Integer anInt = 149
Byte aByte = anInt.byteValue();

String hexFromInt = "".format("0x%x", anInt); // This will output 0x95
String hexFromByte = "".format("0x%x", aByte); // This will output 0x95
```

**Converting an array of bytes to a hex string:**
As far as I know there is no simple function to convert all the elements inside an array of some `Object` to elements of another `Object`, So you have to do it yourself. You can use the following functions:

**From byte[] to String:**

```
    public static String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] byteArray){
        String hexString = "";

        for(int i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++){
            String thisByte = "".format("%x", byteArray[i]);
            hexString += thisByte;
        }

        return hexString;
    }
```

**And from hex string to byte[]:**

```
public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String hexString){
    byte[] bytes = new byte[hexString.length() / 2];

    for(int i = 0; i < hexString.length(); i += 2){
        String sub = hexString.substring(i, i + 2);
        Integer intVal = Integer.parseInt(sub, 16);
        bytes[i / 2] = intVal.byteValue();
        String hex = "".format("0x%x", bytes[i / 2]);
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

It is too late but I hope this could help some others ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you like streams, here is a single-expression version of the format-and-concatenate approach:

```
String hex = IntStream.range(0, bytes.length)
                      .map(i -> bytes[i] & 0xff)
                      .mapToObj(b -> String.format("%02x", b))
                      .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

It's a shame there isn't a method like `Arrays::streamUnsignedBytes` for this.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding my two cents as I see many answers using a char array and/or using a StringBuilder instance and claiming to be fast or faster.

Since I had a different idea using the ASCII table organization having 0-9 at code points 48-57 and A-F at 65-70 and a-f at 97-102, I wanted to test which idea is the fastest.

Since I have not done something like that for quite some years now, I am giving this an extensive shoot out. I use 1 billion bytes in different sized arrays (1M, 1K, 10) so we have 1000 times 1M bytes per array, 1M times 1000 bytes per array and 100M times for 10 bytes per array.

Turns out the char array from 1-F wins. Using a char array as output instead of a StringBuilder also wins hands down (less objects, no test of capacity and no new array nor copying when growing). Furthermore you seem to get a small penalty when using a foreach (for(var b : bytes)) loop.

The version using my idea was approx. 15% slower for 1M bytes per array, 21% slower for 1000 bytes per array and 18% slower for 10 bytes per array. The StringBuilder version was 210%, 380% and 310% slower.

Bad but not that unexpected as a lookup of small arrays in first level cache beats one if and an add... . (one cache access + offset calculation vs. one if, one jump, one add -> not sure about the jump thou).

My version:

```
public static String bytesToHex(byte [] bytes) {
    
    char [] result = new char [bytes.length * 2];
    
    for(int index = 0; index < bytes.length; index++) {
        int v = bytes[index]; 

        int upper = (v >>> 4) & 0xF;
        result[index * 2] = (char)(upper + (upper < 10 ? 48 : 65 - 10));
        
        int lower = v & 0xF;
        result[index * 2 + 1] = (char)(lower + (lower < 10 ? 48 : 65 - 10));
    }
    
    return new String(result);
}
```

PS: Yes I did multiple runs and took the best run each, did warm up and also did runs with 10 billion characters to be sure same picture... .

Comment: Works good, I can't believe its not until Java 17 that this facility was added. I was trying to match MessageDigest hashes to stored hash values.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Tink, then there is:

```java
package com.google.crypto.tink.subtle;

public final class Hex {
  public static String encode(final byte[] bytes) { ... }
  public static byte[] decode(String hex) { ... }
}
```

so something like this should work:

```java
import com.google.crypto.tink.subtle.Hex;

byte[] bytes = {-1, 0, 1, 2, 3 };
String enc = Hex.encode(bytes);
byte[] dec = Hex.decode(enc)
```

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
Integer.toHexString((int)b);
```

Comment: there are not extra leading zerous!