# Format specifier for hex not working in java

Tags: java, format, printf

I always get an exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.FormatFlagsConversionMismatchException: Conversion = h, Flags = 0
```

on this line of code

```
String.format("%02H", data[i]);
```

the data array holds char variables.

I want to print these characters in hex format like 09, not only 9.

Comment: "x" is hex. As stated in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use `String.format("%02X", (int)data[i]);` instead.

Take a look at the answers to [Java code To convert byte to Hexadecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817752/java-code-to-convert-byte-to-hexadecimal) for an expanded discussion on the topic.

Comment: Yes. In fact, the conversion character 'H' implies the hash code of the argument, and the flag '0' is not defined for this conversion. And  the '0' flag is not supported for the Character type either. Cast it to an int!

Comment: I solved it. Thanks. The char needs to be casted to byte

Comment: You are right - I'd copy pasted your answer and replaced with the `X` arg but didn't realize you were passing an `int`.  Also, be careful casting `char` to `byte`, that's losing a byte.