# Java mySQL login issue

Tags: java, mysql, easyphp

Hey guys I have a weird problem , if I enter my correct credentials from my database I GET AN ERROR, if I enter the wrong credentials everything is okay.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Column 'username' not found.
This error occurs when I enter the correct credentials
```

Also I have another problem, my passwords are encrypted with MD5 and I have no idea how to write that into my SELECT , tried this but without any success.

```
 resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT password FROM cards.username WHERE username = '" + username + "' && password = 'MD5(" + password + ")'");
```

So this is my class

```
public void readDataBase() throws Exception {

    //Scanners

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Username: ");
    String username = in.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Password: ");
    String password = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println(" ");


    //---------------------

    String databaseUsername = "";
    String databasePassword = "";

    try {
        // this will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        // setup the connection with the DB.

        connect = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/cards?"
                        + "user=root&password=password");

        // statements allow to issue SQL queries to the database

        statement = connect.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT password FROM cards.username WHERE username = '" + username + "' && password = '" + password + "'");
        //writeResultSet(resultSet);

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            databaseUsername = resultSet.getString("username");
            databasePassword = resultSet.getString("password");

        }

        if (username.equals(databaseUsername) && password.equals(databasePassword))

            System.out.println("Success !! ");
        else
            System.out.println(" Failure ");

        //---

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        // resultSet gets the result of the SQL query

        //      resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from FEEDBACK.COMMENTS");
        //      
        //      writeResultSet(resultSet);
        //
        //      // preparedStatements can use variables and are more efficient
        //      preparedStatement = connect
        //          .prepareStatement("insert into  FEEDBACK.COMMENTS values (default, ?, ?, ?, ? , ?, ?)");


        // "myuser, webpage, datum, summary, COMMENTS from FEEDBACK.COMMENTS");
        // parameters start with 1
        //      preparedStatement.setString(1, "Test");
        //      preparedStatement.setString(2, "TestEmail");
        //      preparedStatement.setString(3, "TestWebpage");
        //      preparedStatement.setDate(4, new java.sql.Date(2009, 12, 11));
        //      preparedStatement.setString(5, "TestSummary");
        //      preparedStatement.setString(6, "TestComment");
        //      preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        //      preparedStatement = connect
        //          .prepareStatement("SELECT myuser, webpage, datum, summary, COMMENTS from FEEDBACK.COMMENTS");
        //      resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        //      writeResultSet(resultSet);
        //
        //      // remove again the insert comment
        //      preparedStatement = connect
        //      .prepareStatement("delete from FEEDBACK.COMMENTS where myuser= ? ; ");
        //      preparedStatement.setString(1, "Test");
        //      preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        //      
        //      resultSet = statement
        //      .executeQuery("select * from FEEDBACK.COMMENTS");
        //      writeMetaData(resultSet);
        //      

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 


    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        close();
    }

}
```

And this is another class where I call this method

```
package mysqltryouts;

import java.util.Scanner;
import mysqltryouts.MySQLtryouts;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MySQLtryouts dao = new MySQLtryouts();
        dao.readDataBase();
    }
}
```

This is my simple DB with only 1 table : 
[image]

I am kinda new with this mySQL and Java stuff, any help would be really appreciated

*EDIT #1
Fixed the main problem, but I still don't know how to make the MD5 thing, I mean when I enter my password in java, it gets itself crypted, I've used this method in VB.NET and tried an equivalent but with no success. :

```
Dim SqlQuery As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) From users1 WHERE username = @Username AND password = MD5(@Password); "
```

My java attempt:

```
resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM cards.username WHERE username = '" + username + "' AND password = ('MD5(" + password + ")'");
```

Comment: is your table name `username`?

Comment: Database Name : cards
Table name    : username

Comment: Try and instead if &&

Comment: I don't understand, can you please be a little more explicit, ambarox ?

Comment: i mean in you query bro.

Comment: resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT password FROM cards.username WHERE username = '" + username + "' and password = '" + password + "'"); --> Replace your line with this line

Comment: Dude found the issue, actually the query was wrong because I was selecting password instead of selecting * 
      resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM cards.username WHERE username = '" + username + "' and password = '" + password + "'");
INSTEAD OF
resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT password FROM cards.username WHERE username = '" + username + "' and password = '" + password + "'"); 

But how do I do the MD5 thing ? I have this idea but from VB.NET :
Dim SqlQuery As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) From users1 WHERE username = @Username AND password = MD5(@Password); "

Comment: Check the main thread, you can read it much more clearly.

Comment: What is the data type of `password` field?

Comment: my password field is varchar(10) and I just add MD5 when I manually add the data from phpmyadmin or from my app

Comment: What happens if you do username alone?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17213761/check-login-string-against-password-mysql-jdbc this might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *my password field is varchar(10) and I just add MD5 when I manually add the data from phpmyadmin or from my app*

While retrieving from the table too, apply `MD5` on your `password` input value to compare with database field value.

**SQL statement**:

```
select count(*) > 0 as match_found 
  from table_name
 where username = ?
   and password = md5( ? )
```

In **JAVA**:

Use `PreparedStatement` for value binding with the statement.

```
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement( sqlQuery );
pst.setString( 1, userName );
pst.setString( 2, password );

ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
boolean loginSuccess = false;
if( rs.next() ) {
  loginSuccess = rs.getBoolean( "match_found" );
}
```

Comment: Check my updated answer. `executeQuery()` should be empty for prepared statements when you are binding values. And don't forget the `?` placeholders. Without which `pst` has no meaning.

Comment: What issue did you face?

Comment: Nothing happens, I get the negative of the IF statement, the loginsuccess isn't getting itself to true

Comment: What wer your input for both username and pwd. And what does table have?

Comment: username  - eddye 
password  - 123

This is what my table contains : http://prntscr.com/3d1ek5

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51370/discussion-between-ravinder-and-extremeswat)

Comment: Fixed, the problem came from my password field's dimension, it was a limited varchar (10) the MD5 encryption didn't had enough space. It works now, thanks.