# Android Sqlite insert Drawable to db using rawquery()

Tags: android, sqlite, drawable

I have a table with a Blob datatype column which saves profile pictures (small `Drawlable` object).

Usually i would run the `SqLiteDatabse.insert()` method with `ContentValues` object so all the converting stuff wont be implement by me.

From my own reasons i need to use an `"Insert or Replace"` Sqlite query and to insert the profile picture's Drawable using a String query so i will have to implement my own convertion from `byte[]` to `String` in order to use the SqLiteDatabse.rawQuery() method.

can you please provide a way of doing it manually and not using `ContentValue` object ?

**P.S**

I can solve this by creating 2 queries:

1. check if the raw exists
2. if not - create it, if so - update it

and then i will be able to use the `ContentValue` object conveniently. but it sounds really inefficient to do so...

Answer (score 0):

To insert a blob value with a SQL string, you have to convert the bytes to hex and use a [blob literal](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#litvalue):

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(blob) VALUES(x'123456abcdef')
```

Comment: No. With what particular part of this do you habe a problem?

Comment: converting the byte[] to hex ... should i convert it to hex before the sql query, or should i let the sql system to convert the byte[] string to hex ?

Comment: Only `ContentValues` can handle byte arrays. For usage in a SQL string, you have to do [the conversion yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817752/java-code-to-convert-byte-to-hexadecimal).