# SHA256 in PHP & Java

Tags: java, php, hash, sha256

I'm porting some Java code to PHP code. In Java I have a hash SHA256 code as below:

```
public static String hashSHA256(String input)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    MessageDigest mDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

byte[] shaByteArr = mDigest.digest(input.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    StringBuilder hexStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < shaByteArr.length; i++) {
        hexStrBuilder.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & shaByteArr[i]));
    }

    return hexStrBuilder.toString();
}
```

In PHP, I hash as below:

```
$hash = hash("sha256", utf8_encode($input));
```

I run the sample code with both ***input = "test"***. However, I got 2 hash strings which are not the same:

```
Java: 9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2bb822cd15d6c15b0f0a8
PHP: 9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08
```

Can someone explain to me why and how to get them match each other? Please note that I cannot modify the Java implementation code, only to modify PHP.

Really appreciate!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The PHP version is correct; the SHA-256 checksum of *test* is `9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08`.

The Java version is returning the same checksum with two `0`s stripped out. This is because of the way you're converting bytes into hex. Instead of `&`ing them with `0xFF`, use `String.format()`, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2817883/2765666):

```
hexStrBuilder.append(String.format("%02x", shaByteArr[i]));
```

I realise you say you cannot modify the Java code, but it is **incorrect**!

Answer (score 1):

The PHP version is correct. But we can modify the result to have the same result with java code.

```
function hash256($input) {
    $hash = hash("sha256", utf8_encode($input));
    $output = "";
    foreach(str_split($hash, 2) as $key => $value) {
        if (strpos($value, "0") === 0) {
            $output .= str_replace("0", "", $value);
        } else {
            $output .= $value;
        }
    }
    return $output;
}

echo hash256("test");
```

result: 9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2bb822cd15d6c15b0f0a8

Comment: $output .= $value; instead of the if else worked perfect for me!!