# Charset of Lotus Domino Server

Tags: linux, utf-8, character-encoding, lotus-domino

I've a Java agent (running on Linux server) that manage document attachments, but something wrong with accented chars in their names (ò,è,ù ecc..).

I wrote this code to display the charset used:

```
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
String enc = writer.getEncoding();
System.out.println("CHARSET: " + enc);
```

This display

```
CHARSET: ASCII
```

In a server where everything works fine, same line print:

```
CHARSET: UTF8
```

Servers have same configuration (works with "Internet sites", where "Use UTF-8 for output"   is set to "Yes").

Any idea about parameter to set (Domino/Linux)?

**UPDATE**

I'll try to explain better...

I call an agent through Ajax call.
In parameter, i pass "ààà" string. When i try to decode in UTF-8 inside agent, string is resolved with

```
"???"
```

instead of

```
"ààà"
```

This is what System.out.println() shows in console.

On another Domino server, everything works. I don't understand if it is a matter of server settings or OS settings.

Comment: What code are you using to work with the attachments? Try setting encoding using setEncoding("UTF-8") or if you work with bytes you can use getBytes("UTF-8")

Comment: My understanding is that Linux filesystems do not have an inherent charset encoding. If you see accented characters correctly in your shell or GUI, it's because the locale settings you are using match the settings of the person who created the file. My recommendation is to write code that calles getBytes() with a variety of different charset arguments (utf-8, utf-16, etc.), and print out the results as hex codes.  Match the results up against tables of charset encodings, and see what's really going on.

Comment: Code for hex output: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817752/java-code-to-convert-byte-to-hexadecimal

Comment: May be related to this. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21157964

Answer (score 2):

Just a suggestion, but you could change the first line in your example to be:

```
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream(), 
                                    Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

That will force the OutputStreamWriter to UTF8, and your sample code will show consistent output on both servers.  Without knowing more details, I can't say for sure if that's relevant to the real problem.

Comment: In the update you said, "I don't understand if it is a matter of server settings or OS settings."  Based on the code you've shown so far, I don't think it is a Domino server setting.  It is more likely a JVM setting or a difference in OS behavior.  But even if you find the magic switch, it's probably best to defensively fix the problem in code.  Have any of our suggestions helped?

Comment: Charset.forName("UTF-8") correctly force to UTF-8, but didn't solve the  problem as reported in UPDATE section