# Reading hex files keaping hex values in java

Tags: java, file, hex

I am trying to read a hexadecimal file from java code. All I want is pick the hex values and save it in a String (or any other format) , without convert them. I've already tried with a `BufferedReader`, and saving the values in a `StringBuilder`, but I don't know why the values are automatically converted in decimal values when I use `StringBuilder.toString()` method.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example?

Comment: There is no such thing as a hex file. There are binary files and text files. Hex is a representation, not a datatype. If you want hex in your String you will have to convert it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `java.util.Formatter`. Try this:

```
StringBuilder _stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (byte _byte : byteArray) 
{
        _stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X ", _byte));
}
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817752/java-code-to-convert-byte-to-hexadecimal).

Comment: Must it too obligatory here.

Comment: Why do you mention a class that isn't used in your example code?

Comment: I mean formatting rules: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Comment: That looks pretty good but I have a file, not a byte array, any suggestion?

Comment: Just use the getResourceAsStream(fileName) function, for example, to load your file to the InputStream. And then perform formatting routine.

Comment: `String.format` will make a new Formatter for each and every iterated byte.  A better alternative is to replace the StringBuilder with `Formatter formatter = new Formatter();` (which will create and wrap a StringBuilder internally) and replace the statement inside the loop with `formatter.format("%02X ", _byte);`.  The final result can be achieved with `formatter.toString()`.