# How to regain the hex value of a byte in java?

Tags: java, string

```
private static byte[]theTestText ={0x00,0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44,0x55,0x66,0x77,(byte) 0x88,(byte) 0x99,(byte) 0xAA,(byte) 0xBB,(byte) 0xCC,(byte) 0xDD,(byte) 0xEE,(byte) 0xFF};

String str= new String(theTestText); // converted the byte array to string
char ch = str.charAt(8); // extracting a specific character from string
```

I want to obtain the hex value from the character 'ch' as defined in the original byte array i.e. 0x88. Is there any way to get that?

Comment: Yes there is. Convert the byte to a hex string. Have a look in one of those answers (as it's asked quite often) https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+byte+to+hex

Comment: Is that arbitrary binary data? If it's *actually* text, what text encoding was it encoded with?

Comment: Similar Question has been Answered here Have a Look [Java code To convert byte to Hexadecimal][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817752/java-code-to-convert-byte-to-hexadecimal

Answer (score 0):

To get the hexa value in a string:

```
String str= new String(theTestText); // converted the byte array to string
char ch = str.charAt(8); // extracting a specific character from string
String hex = String.format("%04x", (int) ch); // Converting the char to a string with its hexadecimal value
```

Comment: fffd- this is the hex value that i am getting. Can't i retrieve the original hex value i.e. 0x88;

Comment: I think I don't get your question. In the string hex, you get the initial hex value, isn't it ?