# Write byte array to file in java

Tags: java, file, file-io, arrays

I want to write byte array to txt file. Firstly I want to see that data in eclipse console and I see that data are true. But when I want to write this data into txt file the problem is manifest itself. Txt file is coming with errors.

My code is as follows.

```
FileOutputStream fos;
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream("/usr/text110.txt");
    fos.write(imageInByte);
    fos.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My txt file is as follows. How can I save my byte array to file properly. Please help me.

> \00-0R~\9D\B6\C9\D9\DD\EB\F1\FA\FF\FF\FF\FF\FF\FF\FF\FF\FF\FF\FF\FF\FF\FF\FF\FF\FF\FA\EF\EF\E4\E0\E2\DA\D9\D7\D0\CE\C4\C1\C0\B6\B5\B1\AE\B0\A1\A2\A0\99\9D\99\95\98\92\95\93\8E\92\91\95\85\86\86\86\8A\8A\89\8C\88\8C\84\81\80y}~{||||zzxxwzyusoklnppjqy\81\8E\8F\94\91\97\99\A0\B2\C4\D2\E0\E9\EA\E7\EC\E9\E9\E7\E3\E3\D9\DC\D3\CF\D0\C7\C7\C6\C2ü\BD\B4\B1\AC\A1\A0\9E\97\96\8E\84\84\83\88\85\89znlx{\86\86\8C\90\8D\92\90\90\94\90\95\91\94\92\90\91\89\8B\84\83ungiba[X\cbfbc^SRSSXUKILTVbes|\8C\95\9D\AA\B4\B6\B4\C5\D2\E3\EC\F2\FA\FF\FF\FF\FF\FF\FF\FF\FF\FF\FF\FF\FF\FF\FF\FF\FF\FF\FF\FF\FF\FF\FF\FF\FF\FF\F4\E8\E0\DE\D9\D2\D8\D6\D4\CC\CB\C8\C6\C5\C9ļ\BC\BF\BE\C1\BC\C0\BE\C0\BD\BC\BE\B9\B7\AE\A8\A8\A7\A5\AA\A8\AE\AD\B2\B2\B1\B5\B0\B2\AD\AF\AC\A8\A8\A2\A5\A1\9F\97\8D\8D\91\94\9C\9C\A3\A2\A7\A4\A3\A1\9C\9E\9B\9A\9E\9A\9C\96\8D\8B\90\99\A2\A3\A5\A6\AA\AC\B2\B9\BC\BE\C3\C2\C6\C1¿\B9\BD\B8\BD\B9\BB\B3\AB\97\9A\9A\A1\A0\A5\A2\A4\A2\9F\9E\96\98\91\90\89\82\81\81\83\83\86\86\82\80vwtyx}}\80\82\83\85\84\86\83\85}\80\80\83~\82}|}|{\80}\82\81\87\86\8B\89\8B\86\85\80xsyy|\80trrv\83\86\93\9F\A5\B1\AC\AE\B6\BC\BF\C9\C9\C9\C9\CD\D6\D4\CF\CD\D8\DB\E4\E2\E8\E9\E8\ED\E9\EF\EA\EE\ED\E8\EA\E2\E4\E2\DE\E0\D9\DB\D2\D3\CB\C9ķ\AA\9A\9B\96\98\9F\9F\A6\A3\A7\A0\A2\99\8D\85\8B\8B\90\8E\93\92\90\93\8F\91\8E\91\8F\90\8A\8A\82\84\80\82\81\81zwla_dmqzy\81~\83\86\82\88\85\86\8A\85\86~zz\81\83\86\80t|}u{\85\85\8F\8E\93\9A\9A\A0\9C\93\8D\93\92\99\93\97\99\93\99\96\9A\9A\95\96\91\89\8D\89\8D\8B\8A\8D\85\89\88\85\8A\84\88\82\82yuqgb^UUQQQJJC?1217387>\bjiowrv~\81\80\88\8C\8A\92\95\92\99\9C\99\9F\A1\9D\A3\A1\A2\A7\A1\A5\A9\A4\A9\AB\A6\AC\AA\AC\B1\AB\B0\B1\AB\B0\AA\AB\AF\A9\AC\AB\A9\AD\A6\A9\A6\A5\A7\9F\A1\A0\9B\9E\96\98\97\91\92\89\8B\87\83\83yzqonfibcaZVJ=.)##!#)($'% -8:FMOX]Yagcjohmqknphlkejiflhjnijmdegadbc_b_VZ]VXRHGAEBLKRSRVQSNQQMNEGIDIDJLJOGJEA=5-))*.+.''..16.*3;:EIKTYU_fbjrou|y|\83\80\82\88\84\85\8B\86\88\8C\86\8A\8E\88\8D\8F\8A\90\90\8E\92\8E\90\94\8E\91\93\8C\90\90\8D\90\89\8C\8C\85\89\82\82\85~\82\80\83~\82\81\82{}|vyqrmih^^TTJF:45.5226.1-0.+.'"!'+*4<9BJGMTPT[[V]_X_VYZUYUTYQU[UZ_Y]aZ\^UWTNOFIMIMQLPOCD?96*'!(+15/4/1+-'#!!  &%),)(  #!',(185=D?ENNPY[Xafahnhotorwquyruyrwysyyu|xz~y|\80z~\80z~~{~wz|twvswqutquprtnrplpimlgiacc\^TVTQRGJH@@550*)!&  " "$+*-687>C?FLFKRPPUUMQQJLGGICHJFLPKQUNSVMQRJMKHJADHAFIDGHAC?9:68369/35110..))*#" " #-/,5<8@FAGOKOVYV]`\ae^be^bd^ab[`]]b]`faeidgkdhjchhbfa`c_`X\VWYRWWTXRVXQURQUMPPIMFHIFGA<:;44./625>8;CEAGH?CC:<53626638748647340+.*-/#),'+)(*!# !
>
> ")&'0229>;BGAGMIKQRNSUPTVORQLOIJNIMQHNRLRVPUXPTVPTTPTQOQGJLBE??B;@A@FAAE?BC;?9=@9<96:311*.''(!   %!$'!'-*05029:59<458200+%!#(&-4/5;439:8:70/(+("'#&,*(+)(*! "!"#%$!
>
> $#)#&.-,4:8>C=@E@=BB=AB>>:992686<@A@>A?=@57911+(*")*)/)&*&*.*+&&(!&%%#!"#"#

Comment: Plz share ur code. Without view ur code, we can't help u.

Comment: Without the code that is doing the writing it's difficult to say. But if you are writing raw binary data to file, it will look odd if you open it in a text editor....

Answer (score 1):

```
FileOutputStream fos = FileOutputStream("path/to/the/file/to/write/in");
fos.write(theByteArray);
fos.close();
```

Will write the byte array *in byte form*.

```
FileOutputStream fos = FileOutputStream("path/to/the/file/to/write/in");
for (byte b : bytes) {
    fos.write(String.format("%02X ", b).getBytes());
}
fos.write(theByteArray);
fos.close();
```

Will write byte array in *human readable form*.

Source:
[Java code To convert byte to Hexadecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817752/java-code-to-convert-byte-to-hexadecimal)
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html