# How to read and download ddd tachograph file with APDU?

Tags: java, smartcard, apdu

I'm trying to read data from a tachograph card using `javax.smartcardio`. The problem is I'm doing most of the things blindly because I can't find a simple tutorial on `APDU commands`.

Currently I managed to print the card type (`card: PC/SC card in HID Global OMNIKEY 3x21 Smart Card Reader 0, protocol T=0, state OK`) and read the card identification information (selected file `0520`).

**How do I download the tachograph .ddd file?**

Here's the code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
            List<CardTerminal> terminals = factory.terminals().list();
            System.out.println("Terminals: " + terminals);
            // get the first terminal
            CardTerminal terminal = terminals.get(0);
            // establish a connection with the card
            Card card = terminal.connect("T=0");
            System.out.println("card: " + card);
            CardChannel channel = card.getBasicChannel();

            byte[] c1 = hexStringToByteArray(stripCommandSpace("00 A4 04 0C 06 FF544143484F"));
            //byte[] c1 = hexStringToByteArray(stripCommandSpace("FF CA 00 00 00"));
            ResponseAPDU r1 = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(c1));
            System.out.println("response: " + byteArrayToHexString(r1.getBytes()));
            byte[] c2 = hexStringToByteArray(stripCommandSpace("00 a4 02 0c 02 05 04"));
            ResponseAPDU r2 = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(c2));
            System.out.println("response: " + byteArrayToHexString(r2.getBytes()));
            byte[] c3 = hexStringToByteArray(stripCommandSpace("00 B0 00 01 128"));
            ResponseAPDU r3 = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(c3));
            System.out.println("response: " + byteArrayToHexString(r3.getBytes()));
            System.out.println("data: " + byteArrayToHexString(r3.getData()));

            byte[] ceva = r3.getData();
            String str = new String(ceva);
            System.out.println("Date card: " + str);

            String fileName = "D:\\fisier\\test.ddd";

            /*BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
        writer.write(str);

        writer.close();*/
            FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            try {
                stream.write(ceva);
            } finally {
                stream.close();
            }

            // disconnect
            card.disconnect(false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exceptie " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I managed to identify and read the driver activity file - I had to change the identifier to `0504` like in the picture below:

[image]

**Now my problem is how to convert the byte array I get into a .ddd file**.

I tried like in the updated version of my code (see above) but the .ddd reader tells me the file is corrupt (I use a third party app which converts .ddd to .txt - called **readesm**).

Comment: Program looks roughly ok, but I have no idea, which access rights are required to read that file. If I remember correctly tachograph cards  understand T=0 only; this would require additional commands to get the response (appropriately called `GET RESPONSE`). What error do you get?

Comment: @guidot I managed to read the desired file, but now I'm facing another problem - how do I convert the byte stream to a ddd file?

Comment: @guidot please see my updated question

Comment: Writing bytes (still unreadable binary stuff) is e.g. described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30920251/1435475) - was that your question?

Comment: Note that depending on what the two methods `hexStringToByteArray()` and `stripCommandSpace()` do, the string "00 B0 00 01 128" might not lead to the command you would expect (i.e. reading 128 bytes starting at offset 1). Also, from looking through some of the open-source projects that work with .ddd files it seems to me that reading only one of the files is not enough. The .ddd file seems to be a concatenation of information from multiple files on the card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structure block in card driver:
[image]

1. structure block is (ICC, IC, Application_Identificacion ........):

   header: "file 2(0501h, 0502h ....) bytes" + "type(data-0 or signed-1) 1 bytes" + "length 2 bytes" + data(read card):
2. ICC,IC and Card_donwload not necessary signed, so 0501 to 0522(not 050e), signed block  file is necessary for authority but not necessary for read byte file and create binary file.
3. Read recursive for Fid:

   ```
    for (Fid fid : Fid.values()) {
       System.out.println(fid.getId());
       // not read 03f00 and 0500 not files
       if(!fid.getId().equals("3f,00") && !fid.getId().equals("05,00")){
           b = readCard(r, channel, fid.getId());
           // header block file
           byte[] htba = OperationHelper.hexToByteAr(fid.getId());
           byte[] sizeByte = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(b.length).array();
           headerBlock[0] = htba[0];       // id file byte 1
           headerBlock[1] = htba[1];       // id file byte 2
           headerBlock[2] = 0;             // type file data
           headerBlock[3] = sizeByte[2];   // size file byte 1
           headerBlock[4] = sizeByte[3];   // size file byte 2
           try{
               fileTGD.write(headerBlock);
               fileTGD.write(b);
               // add signature file
               if (!fid.getId().equals("00,02") && !fid.getId().equals("00,05")
                       && !fid.getId().equals("C1,00") && !fid.getId().equals("C1,08")
                       && !fid.getId().equals("05,0E")){
                   performHashFile(r, channel);
                   b = signature(r, channel);
                   sizeByte = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(b.length).array();
                   headerBlock[0] = htba[0];
                   headerBlock[1] = htba[1];
                   headerBlock[2] = 1;
                   headerBlock[3] = sizeByte[2];
                   headerBlock[4] = sizeByte[3];
                   fileTGD.write(headerBlock);
                   fileTGD.write(b);
               }
           }catch (Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Read datas:

   ```
   public static byte[] readCard( ResponseAPDU r, CardChannel channel, String fid){
   ByteArrayOutputStream dataResponseBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   try {
       //r = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(0x00, 0x84, 0x00, 0x00,  OperationHelper.hexToByteAr("6f,07,00,00,00,08,00,00,00,00,00,a4,02,0c,02,05,04")));
       /**
        *  GetParameters
        *
        *  Headers
        *  CLA - 00
        *  INS - A4
        *  P1 - 02
        *  P2 - 0C
        *  DATA - 00,02         //6C,00,00,00,00,08,01,00,00,00
        *  dataOffset - 00
        *  dataLength - length of trama
        *
        */
       //r = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(0x00, 0xA4, 0x02, 0x0C,  OperationHelper.hexToByteAr("00,02"), 0x00, 0x02));          
       if (!fid.equals("00,02") && !fid.equals("00,05"))
           //select MF - Only positioning
           r = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(0x00, 0xA4, 0x04, 0x0C, OperationHelper.hexToByteAr("ff,54,41,43,48,4f"), 0x00, 0x06));
       // select EF
       r = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(0x00, APDUCommand.SELECT_FILE.getCommand(), 0x02, 0x0C, OperationHelper.hexToByteAr(fid), 0x00, 0x02));
       boolean end = true;
       int p1 = 0x00;
       int p2 = 0x00;
       Byte le = Byte.valueOf((byte) 255);
       int size = 0x00;
       do {
           r = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(0x00, APDUCommand.READ_BINARY.getCommand(), p1, p2, (le < 0) ? le & 255 : le));
           switch (r.getSW1()) {
               case 0x90:
                   dataResponseBuffer.write(r.getData());
                   size += (le < 0) ? le.intValue() & 255 : le.intValue();
                   byte[] offsetarray = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(size).array();
                   p1 = (offsetarray[2] < 0) ? offsetarray[2] & 255 : offsetarray[2];
                   p2 = (offsetarray[3] < 0) ? offsetarray[3] & 255 : offsetarray[3];
                   break;
               case 0x67: // dec 103                   
                   break;
               // normal process XX = number of bytes for response enabled
               case 0x61:
               /*
                nuevaLong = Byte.valueOf(codigoError[1]);
                */
                   break;
               // incorrect parameters (out of EF)
               case 0x6a:
                   if (r.getSW2() == 0x86)
                       System.out.println("Parameters P1-P2 incorrects");
                   break;
               // incorrect long, sw2 = exact long. If not return field data
               case 0x6c: //dec 108
                   //nuevaLong = Byte.valueOf(codigoError[1]);
                   if (r.getSW2() == 0x86)
                       System.out.println("Parameter P1-P2 incorrects");
                   break;
               case 0x69: //dec 108
                   end = false;
                   break;
               case 0x6b: //dec 107
                   end = false;
                   /*
                   int div = (le < 0)? le.intValue() & 255: le.intValue() ;
                   size -= div;
                   le = Byte.valueOf((byte) (div / 2));
                   size += le;
                   if (le.byteValue() == (byte) 0) {
                       le = Byte.valueOf((byte) 1);
                       end = false;
                   }
                   offsetarray = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(size).array();
                    entero = Integer.valueOf(byteArraySize4ToInt(offsetarray) );
                   p1 = (offsetarray[2] < 0)? offsetarray[2] & 255: offsetarray[2];
                   p2 = (offsetarray[3] < 0)? offsetarray[3] & 255: offsetarray[3];
                   */
                   break;

               default:
                   break;
           }
       } while (end);
   } catch (CardException e1) {
       e1.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return dataResponseBuffer.toByteArray();
   ```

   }

   5.for making the errors according to the documentation inside the switch