# How do I find out if my current build is signed?

Tags: android, apk, signed-apk

I want to perform a code operation only under the assumption that the current build is a signed APK. Is there a way to programmatically find out?

Comment: Could this be the answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32954404/verifying-an-apk-programmatically-using-jarsigner

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if you're running a debug build with `BuildConfig.DEBUG`. If this shows up as false, you're on a release build. For example:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    Log.d(TAG, "This is a debug build");
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "This is a release build");
}
```

Comment: The question is about signed/unsigned. not about release or debug.

Answer (score 0):

[PackageInfo.signatures](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#signatures) contains the array of all signatures read from the package file. This can be obtained using [PackageManager.getInstalledPackages()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledPackages(int)) with `GET_SIGNATURES` flag.