# Spark 1.4 Scala Dataframe binary to hex

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have this field in my dataframe: `myField: binary (nullable = false)` (originally a Java byte[16]).

How do I select it and show it as a `hex` in scala from a spark shell? Please include necessary imports.

Comment: what have you tried? do you need information about how to convert binary to hex? or how to apply this function to your RDD? basically... `mydf.select("myField").rdd.map(binToHex(_))`

Comment: do I need to convert it to an rdd first? Is there an equivalent dataframe function?

Comment: something like `mydf.select("myField").map(binToHex($"myField"))`, but my DF psuedocode is a bit rougher then my rdd, might not even need the select.

Comment: What's the import? I'm getting: error: not found: value binToHex (NOTE: I'm new to everything here)

Comment: you have to code that function up yourself. That why I asked what you were looking for, I know spark, but not how to convert a bin to hex off the top of my head

Comment: there must be an already implemented function somewhere!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817752/java-code-to-convert-byte-to-hexadecimal

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, hex}

df.select(hex(col("myField")))
```

Answer (score 0):

So I generalized @user6022341 solution to the following function

```
  def castBinaryToHexString(inputSrcDF: DataFrame):DataFrame={
    var srcDF = inputSrcDF

    // get all column names
    val allCols = srcDF.schema.fields.map(f => f.name.toLowerCase())

    // get all columns with data type = BinaryType
    val dateCols = srcDF.schema.fields.filter(f => f.dataType == BinaryType).map(f => f.name.toLowerCase())

    // cast all binary types to hex string
    srcDF = srcDF.select(allCols.map(x => if (dateCols.contains(x)) concat(lit("0x"),hex(col(x))).alias(x) else col(x) ): _*)

    return srcDF
  }
```