# Hashing a password in java and trying to convert in string

Tags: java, hash

I actually have a problem with `hashing a password` and trying to convert in string to put it in a database.

Currently I have this code

```
            MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            byte[] hash = digest.digest(motsDePasse.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            String fileString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hash);
```

The deal is that it does not give me the good hash. Let's say I try to hash "`12345`". It should give me `5994471abb01112afcc18159f6cc74b4f511b99806da59b3caf5a9c173cacfc5`.

But it actually return `WZRHGrsBESr8wYFZ9sx0tPURuZgG2lmzyvWpwXPKz8U=`

Comment: The value WZRHGrsBESr8wYFZ9sx0tPURuZgG2lmzyvWpwXPKz8U= in Base64 is 5994471ABB01112AFCC18159F6CC74B4F511B99806DA59B3CAF5A9C173CACFC5 in Hex.  You just need to encode using Hex instead of Base64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using a hex encoder

```
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    byte[] hash = digest.digest("12345".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    String hex = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(hash);
    System.out.println(hex);
```

**output**

5994471ABB01112AFCC18159F6CC74B4F511B99806DA59B3CAF5A9C173CACFC5

Answer (score 0):

You are Base64 encoding it.  If you Hex encode it, you will get the output you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You're encoding your bytes in base 64. If you want to encode it in hexadecimal, try here: [Java code To convert byte to Hexadecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817752/java-code-to-convert-byte-to-hexadecimal). If you're putting into a database as a string though, base64 should be fine for your needs.