# How to convert a byte/integer to a hexadecimal to carve a file

Tags: java, arrays, file, byte, filestream

```
int[] png = { -119, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10 };
```

should be equal to an array of string as follows.

89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A

I have tried with Integer.toHexString(-119) but it end up converting into ffffff89 
but it should be equal to 89.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java code To convert byte to Hexadecimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817752/java-code-to-convert-byte-to-hexadecimal)

Answer (score 0):

StringBuffer and format() of [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) Class can help you here.

For example,

```
String.format("%02X ", value);
```

Here is how you can iterate through the array to convert it to Hex.

```
public class ConvertToHexaDecimal {

    static int[] png = { -119, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10 };

    public static void main(String[] args){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int value : png ) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02X ", value));
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: private static String   digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
  public static String toHex(byte[] data){
      StringBuffer    buf = new StringBuffer();

      for (int i = 0; i != data.length; i++)
      {
          int v = data[i] & 0xff;

          buf.append(digits.charAt(v >> 4));
          buf.append(digits.charAt(v & 0xf));
      }

      return buf.toString();
  }

This Worked ... :)