# How store values greater than 127 in byte datatype in java

Tags: java, android

How store values greater than 127 in byte datatype in java.

```
int b = 160;
System.out.println((byte)b);
```

It prints **-96**.

> Note :  I want to write bytes on a BLE device. So can not convert it
>   to short or int.

Comment: Don't store them in a byte. Use short or int.

Comment: Well, I guess you shouldn't use a byte :P

Comment: You are storing in int and typecasting it to byte. This is what you will get.

Comment: Store in b/127 no of array of bytes. And sum all at last

Comment: Why you are typecasting in byte.. explain purpose briefly

Comment: Please don't downvote on the grounds of obviousness; that is subjective.

Comment: @Vishva Dave, I want to write bytes on a BLE device. So can not convert it to short or int.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java code To convert byte to Hexadecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817752/java-code-to-convert-byte-to-hexadecimal)

Answer (score 8):

You might want to store a value in the range 128-255 in a byte. You can, provided you don't also want to store a value -128 to -1 in the same byte (at a different time, obviously).

Just use the bitwise and operator when you want to read it:

```
b & 0xff
```

Answer (score 0):

The *range* of a `byte` is the inclusive range -128 to +127.

You can't store a number greater than 127 in a `byte`, although you can abuse the range -128 to -1. Your output -96 is attained since the eight bit pattern of -96 matches 160 written in binary. Crudely, you *can* recover your original number if you add 256 to any negative, or mask all apart from the final 8 bits using `b & 256`.

If you want to store 160 then use a `char` (0 to 65535), a `short`, or an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

For this reason use `int` or `long`.

Comment: this is more a comment rather than an answer