# Converting a byte[] to a String in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, hex

Say we have a `byte[]` array:

```
byte[] data = {10,10,1,1,9,8}
```

and I want to convert these values in to a hexadecimal string:

```
String arrayToHex = "AA1198"
```

How can I do this? Using Java language in IntelliJ. Keep in mind this is my first semester of coding, so I'm already feeling lost.

First I start with this method:

```
public static String toHexString(byte[] data)
```

In the problem I'm trying to solve, we get a string from a user input, which is then converted to a byte[] array, and from there must be converted back into a string in hexadecimal format. But for simplification purposes I am just trying to input my own array. 
So, here I have my array:

```
byte[] data = {10,10,1,1,9,8}
```

I know how to just print the byte array by just saying:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
  System.out.print(data[i]);
}
```

which will have an output of:

```
10101198
```

but obviously this is not what I'm looking for, as I have to convert the 10s to As, and I need a String type, not just an output. I'm sorry I'm so vague, but I'm truly lost and ready to give up!

Comment: Show your own effort and code to solve the problem (as properly formatted text in the question)

Comment: Should 10 really map to just A, not 0A? What should happen with value that have an upper nibble different from zero?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java code To convert byte to Hexadecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817752/java-code-to-convert-byte-to-hexadecimal)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817752/java-code-to-convert-byte-to-hexadecimal

Comment: use Integer.toHexString(data[i]); instead of data[i] in the loop

Answer (score 2):

This is not what you would normally do and would only work for byte values from 0 to 15.

```
byte[] data = {10,10,1,1,9,8};
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (byte b : data)
    sb.append(Integer.toHexString(b));
String arrayAsHex = sb.toString();
```

What you would normally expect is "0A0A01010908" so that any byte value is possible.

```
String arrayAsHex = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(data);
```

Comment: thank you! For this particular assignment, we only need it to work for 0 to 15, so that's exactly what I need.