# Leading zeros when computing SHA-256 hash

Tags: java, android, python, hash, sha256

I am trying to compare the SHA-256 hash values of the same file with Python and Java. However, in some instances, the Python hash value has leading zeros, whereas the Java version does not. For instance, hashing *somefile.txt* in both programs yields:

Python: `000c3720cf1066fcde30876f498f060b0b3ad4e21abd473588f1f31f10fdd890`

Java : `c3720cf1066fcde30876f498f060b0b3ad4e21abd473588f1f31f10fdd890`

Is it safe to simply remove leading 0's and compare or is there an implementation which does not produce the leading zeros?

**Python Code**

```
def sha256sum(filename):
    h  = hashlib.sha256()
    b  = bytearray(128*1024)
    mv = memoryview(b)
    with open(filename, 'rb', buffering=0) as f:
        for n in iter(lambda : f.readinto(mv), 0):
            h.update(mv[:n])
    return h.hexdigest()

print(sha256sum('/somepath/somefile.txt'))

# 000c3720cf1066fcde30876f498f060b0b3ad4e21abd473588f1f31f10fdd890
```

**Java Code**

```
public static String calculateSHA256(File updateFile) {
    MessageDigest digest;
    try {
        digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception while getting digest", e);
        return null;
    }

    InputStream is;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(updateFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception while getting FileInputStream", e);
        return null;
    }

    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int read;
    try {
        while ((read = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            digest.update(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        byte[] shaSum = digest.digest();
        BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1, shaSum);
        String output = bigInt.toString(16);
        return output;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to process file for SHA256", e);
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception on closing SHA256 input stream", e);
        }
    }
}

Log.i("Output", calculateSHA256(somefile))

// I/Output: c3720cf1066fcde30876f498f060b0b3ad4e21abd473588f1f31f10fdd890
```

Comment: It's because you are using `BigInteger`. I think that it is this that is stripping off leading zeros.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `BigInteger` conversion is ignoring leading zeros in your SHA-256 hash. Instead you should encode `byte[]` directly. As suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2817883/1602555) you can use `String.format()`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (byte b : shaSum) {
    sb.append(String.format("%02X", b));
}
return sb.toString();
```

When encoded as hex string the SHA-256 value has 64 characters, as per [wiki example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2#Test_vectors):

> SHA256("")
>
> 0x e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855

Comment: Note that the "%02X" format will uppercase the string (see the Javadoc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)). Use "%02x" if you want the preserve the lowercase letters.