# Hex data wont print in my BLE Scanner App

Tags: java, android-studio, hex, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to make a BLE scanner using Android studio (JAVA). I am using a model code from here:https://github.com/joelwass/Android-BLE-Scan-Example

I have edited the code to filter for one single device I am currently using as the broadcaster ( the CC2640R2 Dev board).

I want to be able to print the Hex data stream that I would receive from the broadcast, so that i can use it to define different types of the development board as well as other informative packets.

From my research i have looked into the **getBytes()** function but am still yet to find a way it works.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.joelwasserman.androidbletutorial;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanRecord;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BluetoothManager btManager;
    BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
    BluetoothLeScanner btScanner;
    Button startScanningButton;
    Button stopScanningButton;
    TextView peripheralTextView;
    private final static int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        peripheralTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PeripheralTextView);
        peripheralTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        startScanningButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StartScanButton);
        startScanningButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startScanning();
            }
        });

        stopScanningButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StopScanButton);
        stopScanningButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopScanning();
            }
        });
        stopScanningButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        btManager = (BluetoothManager)getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        btAdapter = btManager.getAdapter();
        btScanner = btAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();


        if (btAdapter != null && !btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent,REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }

        // Make sure we have access coarse location enabled, if not, prompt the user to enable it
        if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("This app needs location access");
            builder.setMessage("Please grant location access so this app can detect peripherals.");
            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
            builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }
    }

    // Device scan callback.
    private ScanCallback leScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {


            if(new String("SimpleBLEBroadcaster").equals(result.getDevice().getName()))
                peripheralTextView.append("Device Name: " + result.getDevice().getName() + " rssi: " + result.getRssi() + "\n" + ScanRecord.getBytes() );
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    System.out.println("coarse location permission granted");
                } else {
                    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setTitle("Functionality limited");
                    builder.setMessage("Since location access has not been granted, this app will not be able to discover beacons when in the background.");
                    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        }

                    });
                    builder.show();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void startScanning() {
        System.out.println("start scanning");
        peripheralTextView.setText("");
        startScanningButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        stopScanningButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                btScanner.startScan(leScanCallback);
            }
        });
    }

    public void stopScanning() {
        System.out.println("stopping scanning");
        peripheralTextView.append("Stopped Scanning");
        startScanningButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        stopScanningButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                btScanner.stopScan(leScanCallback);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The error i get from this is: ***Error:(97, 140) error: non-static method getBytes() cannot be referenced from a static context***

Any help on how to correctly print the hex stream would be much appreciated!

Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to solve this using  https://stackoverflow.com/users/344480/matthias answer found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2817883/344480

Answer (score 1):

The method `getBytes()` can only be called on an *instance* of `ScanRecord`. You can get one from the `ScanResult`:

```
peripheralTextView.append("Device Name: " + result.getDevice().getName() + " rssi: " + result.getRssi() + "\n" + result.getScanRecord().getBytes() );
```

I don't know what a `ScanRecord` represents, but at least that's how your code compiles. Probably you want to represent the bytes as string in this case?

```
peripheralTextView.append("Device Name: " + result.getDevice().getName() + " rssi: " + result.getRssi() + "\n" + new String(result.getScanRecord().getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8) );
```

Comment: Currently i have found a way to use getBytes as a string variable and printed that, however it gives me a 7 digit code of random symbols letters and numbers. Which is incorrect as the output states a packet length of 62. What i need is a way to convert it to Hex

Comment: This might help, if the raw bytes are in fact hex values: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2817883/344480